# What is this "Company" Kazami Yuuji works for anyway?

Tags: grisaia

In the Grisaia no Kajitsu, Kazami Yuuji works for a company related to Ichigaya and the Japanese government.

But he very often states that the Japanese branch is indeed a branch of the main corporation in America.

So it seems to be some intelligence and special ops agency, but in a worldwide aspect.

What is this corporation exactly? Asahi Cleaning LLC is the front, that is not what I am asking.

Looking for answers from the VN, since the first season of the anime does not delve too deep into this.